# Do you recommend using Docker on WSL? Or better to use natively on Windows?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

Or maybe to install VirtualBox/Vagrant and run Docker there?

The only requirement I have is that my machine's OS needs to be Windows as there are other stuff running in there.

But I usually have compatibility problems and weird stuff happening to mounted volumes when I use Docker on WSL.

Comment: WSL has some [I/O performance issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/873). I think, Hyper-V+Docker is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just my opinion but if you should use Windows and already have the virtual box it's better to use the docker in VirtualBox with Linux on board.

In this way, you will have fewer compatibility problems and good performance with your mounting folders(in case if folders do not mount from host Windows)

Also in this way, you can avoid Hyper-V problem with docker and virtualbox on host machine